# Including Wix Setup Project Output in Wix Bundle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have created a Wix Setup project and a Wix bundle project in the same solution. I included the msi file of the Setup project as the source of a package in the bundle application. (It has a reference to the setup application)

I have found that if I try to build the whole solution at the same time I get an error when trying to install the boostrapper "failed to find payload..."

However, if i build the setup project and then the boostrapper it installs without any problems.

Why is this?? It seems that it's grabbing the past installer before the setup project is finished building the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the .msi project in the bundle project. That's how you tell MSBuild the bundle depends on the .msi.

Comment: It does have a reference to it and it is building. I found that this problem only occurs when i do a "rebuild" in visual studio.